# loading a large JSON object in Firefox 17.0.5

Tags: ajax, json, firefox, memory

I am loading a large (~300 MB) JSON file by using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: path,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        async: false, 
        success: function(json_object) {
            console.log("success!");
        } error: function(request, error) {
            console.log(request["statusText"]);
        }
    });
```

Running it outputs "InternalError: allocation size overflow". Is there any way to get around this that does not involve making the file smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set up a buffer. However, why on earth are you passing so much data? That would be an extremely unreasonable wait for any user.

**EDIT**

Buffering isn't really something you can do from the ajax side (according to [How to buffering an Ajax Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755269/how-to-buffering-an-ajax-request)). However, you can set something up server side (if it's your server returning the data) to send it in pieces, then use ajax to request each piece.

If it's not your server, or your requesting from an API or something, then look and see if they accept any parameters to define the size of the return object - this way you can request it in chunks.

Comment: It's something that I'm building for a small group of users that doesn't mind waiting a bit for this data. The data all goes into a d3 visualization. Could you give me some more details about how to set up this buffer? Thanks.